# No repetitive jQuery UI droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a shopping cart kinda thing using jQuery UI drag 'n drop functionality. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/m3x1k8Lu/
My question is how i can avoid having repetitive items. I want to make a limitation so that no one can add more that one L2 to the cart.

```
$( "#relations ol" ).droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
    $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: I checked out your fiddle, but cant seem to figure out how it works. Could you do an indexOf to see if the item to add is already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m3x1k8Lu/1/

We only accept a specific class, and removing it from the draggable when it is dropped:

```
accept: ".special",
drop: function (event, ui) {
  $(ui.draggable).removeClass('special');
```

The problem is I had to remove the selector: `:not(.ui-sortable-helper)` from the accept event. You have to figure out how to use multiple selectors with this format